# What's the current way to add jQuery to an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core

First I tried Nuget, but that says to use Bower.

Then I tried Bower, but that says you shouldn't use it either.

What's the "correct" way to add jQuery to an ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: Use `npm` or `yarn`

Comment: As far as I know, `bower.json` is the correct approach. Do you see any error when you add it to `bower.json`?

Comment: From their website: "...psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend using Yarn and Webpack for front-end projects read how to migrate! "

Comment: NPM isn't a complete package manager. All it does is download files, you still need a way to reliably get them into the right place.

Comment: For such a widely used library, why not simply use a CDN instead? e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery